# Oracle SQL - Optimizing multiple Left joins

Tags: sql, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working on a huge project (meaning an insane number of columns but not a ton of rows). I'm rewriting someone else's code and they have 25 left joins, 1 for each column. It's performing a cross-walk of sorts in that there is a `dx_ID`, `dx_Code` and `dx_Desc`.

It was running just fine up until a few days ago and now it's stalling out here. There has to be a better way of doing this. Does anyone have any ideas?

I have a dummy query below to illustrate what's going on. I didn't type out all 25 columns, but you get the idea. It will sooner rather than later be transferred over to Snowflake, so if there's a solution that works in both that would be preferable. If not both then Snowflake.

Here is what I tried. It was working but now it's stalling/timing out.

```sql
WITH

  GET_CLAIM_DATA AS (
    SELECT
      '123456789' AS CLAIM_ID,
      'DX1'  AS DX_ID_1,
      'DX2'  AS DX_ID_2,
      'DX3'  AS DX_ID_3,
      'DX25' AS DX_ID_25
    FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT
      '459745630' AS CLAIM_ID,
      'DX1'  AS DX_ID_1,
      'DX25' AS DX_ID_2,
      NULL   AS DX_ID_3,
      NULL   AS DX_ID_25
    FROM DUAL
  )

 ,DIAGNOSIS_CROSSWALK AS (
    SELECT
      'DX1' AS DX_ID,
      '112.4' AS DX_CODE,
      'Flarble' AS DX_DESC
    FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT
      'DX2' AS DX_ID,
      '158.6' AS DX_CODE,
      'Severe flarble' AS DX_DESC
    FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT
      'DX3' AS DX_ID,
      'H65' AS DX_CODE,
      'Blaggle floddle' AS DX_DESC
    FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT
      'DX25' AS DX_ID,
      'H65.7' AS DX_CODE,
      'Headache' AS DX_DESC
    FROM DUAL
  )

 ,GET_DX_CODE AS (
    SELECT /* +MATERIALIZE */
      DX_ID,
      DX_CODE,
      DX_DESC
    FROM DIAGNOSIS_CROSSWALK
  )

SELECT
  CLM.CLAIM_ID,
  DX1.DX_CODE  AS DX_1,
  DX2.DX_CODE  AS DX_2,
  DX3.DX_CODE  AS DX_3,
  DX25.DX_CODE AS DX_25
FROM GET_CLAIM_DATA           CLM
LEFT JOIN GET_DX_CODE         DX1
  ON DX1.DX_ID = CLM.DX_ID_1
LEFT JOIN GET_DX_CODE         DX2
  ON DX2.DX_ID = CLM.DX_ID_2
LEFT JOIN GET_DX_CODE         DX3
  ON DX3.DX_ID = CLM.DX_ID_3
LEFT JOIN GET_DX_CODE         DX25
  ON DX25.DX_ID = CLM.DX_ID_25
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; an English (not code) explanation of the logic you are trying to implement; and the expected output for your sample data. You appear to joining multiple instances of the same sub-query `GET_DX_VIEW` and what you probably want is to use a hierarchical or recursive query but without an explanation of the logic and to see what you expect as the output for some sample data it is difficult to tell.

Comment: it looks that you left join to `GET_DX_CODE` table that looks like a dictionary. If it's like that, i dont see issue with current code, since every column value might have a different row in dict table. You could consider making a view maybe.

Comment: Does each match to `GET_DX_CODE` always match to either zero-or-one row? If it can match to multiple rows then even if it is only 2 rows for each join then with 25 joins that will generate 2^25 combinations of values which will overwhelm most databases.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your SQL (that we can tell without knowing more). What you need to do is look at the *execution plan* that it is following and identify using ASH data or a SQL Monitor report where in that plan it is spending all its time. It could be as simple as an unusable index or a hash join where a nested loops would be more appropriate. Ensure that GET_DX_CODE is a table, not a view or subquery. If it isn't a table, materialize it with a CTE (WITH clause) and hash join to it. If it is a table, ensure DX_ID is indexed and the index is usable.

Comment: As you appear to be joining all your tables in a single chain, after the first LEFT JOIN you can convert all the rest into INNER joins. If DX1 doesn't have a matching record in CLM then you aren't going to get any data from the subsequent tables - and the same logic is true as you work your way down the chain of tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `UNPIVOT` and then `JOIN`:

```sql
WITH GET_DX_CODE AS (
  SELECT /* +MATERIALIZE */
         DX_ID,
         DX_CODE,
         DX_DESC
  FROM   ABC.DIAGNOSIS_CROSSWALK
)
SELECT CLM.CLAIM_ID,
       DX.DX_CODE
FROM   GET_CLAIM_DATA CLM
       UNPIVOT(
         dx_id FOR type IN (
           clm.dx_id_1 AS 1,
           clm.dx_id_2 AS 2,
           clm.dx_id_3 AS 3,
           -- ...
           clm.dx_id_25 AS 25
         )
       ) u
       LEFT JOIN GET_DX_CODE dx
       ON DX.DX_ID = u.dx_id
```

Then, if you need to, you could `PIVOT` back from rows-to-columns.

or you can use correlated sub-queries:

```sql
WITH GET_DX_CODE AS (
  SELECT /* +MATERIALIZE */
         DX_ID,
         DX_CODE,
         DX_DESC
  FROM   ABC.DIAGNOSIS_CROSSWALK
)
SELECT CLM.CLAIM_ID,
       (SELECT DX.DX_CODE FROM get_dx_code dx WHERE dx.dx_id = CLM.dx_id_1) AS dx_1,
       (SELECT DX.DX_CODE FROM get_dx_code dx WHERE dx.dx_id = CLM.dx_id_2) AS dx_2,
       (SELECT DX.DX_CODE FROM get_dx_code dx WHERE dx.dx_id = CLM.dx_id_3) AS dx_3,
       -- ...
       (SELECT DX.DX_CODE FROM get_dx_code dx WHERE dx.dx_id = CLM.dx_id_25) AS dx_25
FROM   GET_CLAIM_DATA CLM
```

Comment: The correlated sub-queries got it. Thank you!  :)